# Re-evaluate the historical lock on 'What are some easter eggs that went wrong'

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, locked-question

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/63342/what-are-some-easter-eggs-that-went-wrong

> What are some easter eggs that went wrong and resulted in unintended consequences, e.g programmer(s) being fired, monetary losses, even human life loss, etc? Please share.

- The question was locked two years ago and has in its four year lifespan only garnered 1764 views as of the time of this writing.
- It has no linked questions
- The answers are *meh* at the best.  Though most are not an easter egg by any definition and just personal annoyances and anecdotes or unintended consequences.

  > My Dad once changed the login screen for an in-house software, that he developed, to a simple and cheerful christmas greeting. Management was not amused.

There really isn't any redeeming qualities to it. I contend that with its low views and very poor answers it doesn't have any historical significance and should be deleted.

Comment: My 2¢: Burn. With. Fire.

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to give the community a chance to disagree, but I think it should be deleted. I don't think that the low view count warrants the historical lock. The net score of the question and top answers is also rather lackluster. There's also not that much insightful (from my perspective, anyway) in the answers, either.

Comment: as a flagger who requested H/L back then, I re-checked flag message and disagree with past self. :) "most answers given provide valuable content and references" - I don't think so anymore. As far as I can see, deletion makes better sense than H/L.

Comment: ...I think I even understand how it happened. Back then, I was flagging bunch of ["nests of link-only answers"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9269313#9269313) for deletion. Not that this question was good, but maybe others were _so much worse_ in comparison that I mistakenly decided it is worth keeping. If moderator who handled the flag also dealt with my flags on other (much worse) questions, he could easily fall into same trap, comparing it to questions he just deleted

Comment: I've never seen this question before but I completely agree with unlocking and deleting it. +1

Comment: I agree with deleting it.  The low view count doesn't warrant HL.